# Change parameter type in SwaggerWcf

Tags: wcf, configuration, swagger, swagger-wcf

Swagger allows setting the [parameter type](http://swagger.io/specification/#pathsObject) but with [SwaggerWcf](https://libraries.io/nuget/SwaggerWcf) I can't edit this file, it's generated. It's set to body by default, but I need it to be path.

One might think `SwaggerWcfParameterAttribute` would allow setting this. But it only allows `Description` and `Required`.

How can it be set specifically?

Comment: Looks like path and query parameters are not supported. Have raised an issue on the author's githubL https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf/issues/74

Comment: @tomredfern Thanks, but using UriTemplate with a variable name enclosed in {} it does recognize that as a path parameter.

Comment: Cool - I've closed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the format in the sample service?

https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf/blob/master/src/SwaggerWcf.Test.Service/IStore.cs#L48

```
    [SwaggerWcfPath("Get book author", "Retrieve the author of a book using the book id")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/books/{id}/author", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    Author ReadBookAuthor(string id);
```

The parameter id from the path will be passed to the function

Comment: Does this mean that the generated swagger defines the parameter as path though? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've tested this and it works. The parameter is not considered of type path.